# Link cell values from embedded excel sheet into word 2013 document

Tags: excel, hyperlink, ms-word, cell

I've managed to copy the cell from the embedded excel sheet and use *Home/Paste special/Paste link/Unformatted text* in the word document body. If I change the cell value in the embedded sheet, the linked field in the document is updated accordingly.
The problem is that, once I close and reopen the word document, the link cannot be updated, it says "word is unable to create a link to the object you specified". If I open the 'edit links to files' pane, the excel worksheet object seems to receive a new name every time the word document is reopened [excel object name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNWDi.jpg)

Do you see a workaround in this situation?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! The document was originally created in a previous version of Word, with the excel object contained inside a table. Probably the table and excel objects were not properly migrated when saving the file to the 2013 .docx format. The solution was to simply delete the table row where the excel was contained, reinsert the row, embed the worksheet and recreate the link from the excel to the document body. It seems that the table and excel object were somehow reinitialized and the link is updating as it should.